# No overload for method 'load_table_1' takes '0' arguments

Tags: c#

```
namespace Gtec_Solution{
    public partial class Main : Form {
        string myconnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username = root;password = 12345V";
        public Main(string userName){

           InitializeComponent();
           load_table_1();
        }

        public void load_table_1(DataTable dt){
           DataTable d;
           Load_Table_Class ld = new Load_Table_Class();
           string Query_1 = "SELECT * FROM gtec_computer.employee";
           d = ld.loading_table(Query_1);
           dataGridView3.DataSource = d;
        }
     }
}

namespace Gtec_Solution{
    public class Load_Table_Class{
        public DataTable loading_table(string Query){
            string myconnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username = root;password = 12345V";
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(myconnection);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, con);
            con.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter mda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            mda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            mda.Fill(dt);
            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = dt;
            mda.Update(dt);
            return dt;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Nice code you have, do you also have a question?

Comment: Error message is clear IMO.

Comment: Looks like you are calling a method with no parameters, when you've defined it such that it takes one param.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the error message says that this call:

```
 load_table_1();
```

is invalid because this method does not have an overload without params. However the parameter `dt` that you have declared for `load_table_1` is not used anyway, so you can safely remove it:

```
    public void load_table_1()
    {
        DataTable d;
        Load_Table_Class ld = new Load_Table_Class();
        string Query_1 = "SELECT * FROM gtec_computer.employee";
        d = ld.loading_table(Query_1);
        dataGridView3.DataSource = d;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `load_table_1(DataTable dt)` does not seem to require or use the parameter `DataTable dt`. Remove it from the signature.

Comment: Thank You..I tried and it worked correctly.....

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a `DataTable` to the method `load_table_1`

You've defined the function as:

```
public void load_table_1(DataTable dt)
    {
        DataTable d;
        Load_Table_Class ld = new Load_Table_Class();
        string Query_1 = "SELECT * FROM gtec_computer.employee";
        d = ld.loading_table(Query_1);
        dataGridView3.DataSource = d;
    }
```

Therefore you need to do:

```
  DataTable dt = new DataTable(); // Or populate it from your service
  load_table_1(dt); // pass the dt object as an argument to load_table_1
```

Or remove the `DataTable` argument from the method. For instance:

```
public void load_table_1()
    {
        DataTable d;
        Load_Table_Class ld = new Load_Table_Class();
        string Query_1 = "SELECT * FROM gtec_computer.employee";
        d = ld.loading_table(Query_1);
        dataGridView3.DataSource = d;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In method `Main`:

```
load_table_1();
```

But elsewhere in class `Main`:

public void load_table_1(DataTable dt)

You need to pass an instance of `DataTable` to `load_table_1`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you call a method with no parameters:

```
public Main(string userName)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    load_table_1();   //THIS LINE

}
```

Yet the method you are calling expects a parameter:

```
public void load_table_1(DataTable dt) // IN HERE
{
    DataTable d;
    Load_Table_Class ld = new Load_Table_Class();
    string Query_1 = "SELECT * FROM gtec_computer.employee";
    d = ld.loading_table(Query_1);
    dataGridView3.DataSource = d;
}
```

This second method doesn't use the param, so just delete it to read:

```
public void load_table_1() // DELETE PARAM HERE
{
    DataTable d;
    Load_Table_Class ld = new Load_Table_Class();
    string Query_1 = "SELECT * FROM gtec_computer.employee";
    d = ld.loading_table(Query_1);
    dataGridView3.DataSource = d;
}
```